# ClassCastException using ObjectInputStream in server-client application

Tags: java, sockets, client-server, classcastexception, objectinputstream

I'm trying to send an object trough sockets, but when I want to read the object in the client I got java.lang.ClassCastException.

My object is the following and I have it in both projects(Server and Client).

```
class Data implements Serializable{

    int height;
    int width;
    int max;
    int zoom;
    int start;
    int end;
    int xMove;
    int yMove;

    public Data(int height, int width, int max, int zoom, int start, int end, int xMove, int yMove){
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;
        this.max = max;
        this.zoom = zoom;
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
        this.xMove = xMove;
        this.yMove = yMove;
    }
}
```

The sending part:

```
try{
    Data dataToSend = new Data(height, width, max, zoom, start, end, xMove, yMove);
    out.writeObject(dataToSend);
}
```

The receiver part:

```
try{
    InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
    Data dataToRead = (Data)ois.readObject();
}
```

And the error message:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: lab05_server.Data cannot be cast to lab05_kliens.Data
```

I tried everything with the same result.
I can't find my mistake.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the same SerializableID added to both Data classes, take a look at :[this](http://www.mkyong.com/java-best-practices/understand-the-serialversionuid/)

Comment: I declared this in both files: private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;    and now I got the following error:  Error0 :java.io.InvalidClassException: lab05_server.Data; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 1, local class serialVersionUID = -5600343588571323555

Comment: One class is correct as it is showing the ID as what you declared it : "1", the other is still picking up the default ID: "-5600343588571323555"

Comment: Yepp, I found the bug, in the client in the (Datas)ois.readObject(); part the Data's constructor isn't executed(I put there a test ouptup). How can I make the casting to work? Thank you.

Comment: The main take away from the link is the part that says "The two classes need to have the same package".

Comment: Thank you for help, unfortunately I need the two different packages because of the server-client structure, so I will remain at passing strings. Anyhow, thank you for helping me out.